# Data validation in google sheets based on the sum

Tags: google-sheets

I need to block a column (let's say column A) when the sum of the values in it reaches 50. So for example in cell B2 i make =50-sum(A1:A1000). Then for a A1:A100 i make a data validation with a custom formula "=B$2$>0" and click "Reject input". It works great with one big but. Data validation acts before the sum formula, so when you enter the value that actually make the sum above 50 it accept it. Only the next value entered after the sum is above 50 is rejected. Is there a way to reject also the value that actually cross the desired sum level?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your custom validation rule (on A1:A1000) to:

`=sum($A$1:$A$1000)<=50`

[image]